# What query languages are available for querying linked data?

Tags: rdf, sparql, linked-data

I'm familiar with SPARQL, but when talking about SPARQL & linked data with people, occasionally they make comments about SPARQL not being a good query language, or having issues with the spec.

So, naturally, I'd like to know, what other query languages exist for querying linked data?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, SPARQL is the W3C recommended language for RDF and it is pretty powerful. But if you want to build a tool which will query linked data, then you might wanna take a look at **Jena**. Its a java API library for handling RDF and its pretty powerful. Also, I had come across another language called, [XSPARQL](http://xsparql.deri.org/) , which gives a nice interoperability between SPARQL and XQuery. If you are familiar with XQuery and SPARQL, you might find XSPARQL useful